# Google spreadsheet - QUERY changes time format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have this column with amounts of time (format set to *number > duration*), if I made a query of that column I get it with a different time format and I'm not able to set the proper format back again. It automatically goes from **duration** to **time**, and if I apply the duration format  it changes my values, please see the example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZLdWXp6mLD32TcWSFSzFJuikPSC1kzbFvJg3JOLjGgA/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please format A3 as Duration and ColumnF as `h:mm:ss`.

Comment: Did not work as seen on a lot of test hours on the test spreadsheet (e.g. 45:00 and 25:00).